# XmlNodeList remains empty - why is that so?

Tags: c#, xml

Okay, this had me occupied for several hours now and still I have no explanation for it:
My XML starts like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<ISO15745Profile xmlns="http://www.profibus.com/GSDML/2003/11/DeviceProfile" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.profibus.com/GSDML/2003/11/DeviceProfile ..\XSD\GSDML-DeviceProfile-v2.1.xsd">
<ProfileHeader>
    <ProfileIdentification>PROFINET Device Profile</ProfileIdentification>
    <ProfileRevision>1.00</ProfileRevision>
    <ProfileName>Device Profile for PROFINET Devices</ProfileName>
    <ProfileSource>PROFIBUS Nutzerorganisation e. V. (PNO)</ProfileSource>
    <ProfileClassID>Device</ProfileClassID>
    <ISO15745Reference>
        <ISO15745Part>4</ISO15745Part>
        <ISO15745Edition>1</ISO15745Edition>
        <ProfileTechnology>GSDML</ProfileTechnology>
    </ISO15745Reference>
</ProfileHeader>
<ProfileBody>
    <DeviceIdentity DeviceID="0x000A" VendorID="0x00B0">
        <InfoText TextId="InfoTextId1"/>
        <VendorName Value="Phoenix Contact GmbH"/>
    </DeviceIdentity>
    <DeviceFunction>
        <Family MainFamily="I/O" ProductFamily="Inline"/>
    </DeviceFunction>
    <ApplicationProcess>
        <DeviceAccessPointList>
            <DeviceAccessPointItem ID="DIM 1" FixedInSlots="0" PhysicalSlots="0..64" MinDeviceInterval="32" ModuleIdentNumber="0x00000300" DNS_CompatibleName="IL-PN-BK-2TX" ImplementationType="ERTEC200" ObjectUUID_LocalIndex="1">
                <ModuleInfo>
                    <Name TextId="IL PN BK DI8 DO4 2TX"/>
                    <InfoText TextId="InfoTextId1"/>
                    <VendorName Value="Phoenix Contact"/>
                    <OrderNumber Value="2703994"/>
                </ModuleInfo>
                <SubslotList>
                    <SubslotItem SubslotNumber="32768" TextId="SubSlot_Interface"/>
                    <SubslotItem SubslotNumber="32769" TextId="SubSlot_Port1"/>
                    <SubslotItem SubslotNumber="32770" TextId="SubSlot_Port2"/>
                </SubslotList>
                <IOConfigData MaxInputLength="512" MaxOutputLength="512"/>
                <UseableModules>
                    <ModuleItemRef FixedInSlots="1" ModuleItemTarget="1"/>
                    <ModuleItemRef AllowedInSlots="4..64" ModuleItemTarget="2"/>
                    <ModuleItemRef AllowedInSlots="4..64" ModuleItemTarget="3"/>
                    <ModuleItemRef AllowedInSlots="4..64" ModuleItemTarget="4"/>
                    <ModuleItemRef AllowedInSlots="4..64" ModuleItemTarget="5"/>
                    <ModuleItemRef AllowedInSlots="4..64" ModuleItemTarget="6"/>
...
```

Now what I'm trying to do is work with the AllowedInSlots, but when creating a XmlNodeList with

```
XmlDocument gsdml = new XmlDocument();
gsdml.Load(fpfad);

XmlNodeList ModuleItemRef = gsdml.SelectNodes("/ISO15745Profile/ProfileBody/ApplicationProcess/DeviceAccessPointList/DeviceAccessPointItem/UseableModules");
```

that XmlNodeList remains empty. What am I doing wrong? I thought that maybe I had to work with the Namespacemanager and tried that, but that didn't do anything.

This is what I tried earlier:

```
XmlDocument gsdml = new XmlDocument();
gsdml.Load(fpfad);

XmlNamespaceManager mgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(gsdml.NameTable);
mgr.AddNamespace("iso", "http://www.profibus.com/GSDML/2003/11/DeviceProfile");
XmlNodeList ModuleItemRef = gsdml.SelectNodes("/iso:ISO15745Profile/ProfileBody/ApplicationProcess/DeviceAccessPointList/DeviceAccessPointItem/UseableModules", mgr);
```

It didn't work, though, so something there has to be wrong.

2nd Edit:
Including the prefix with every part of the path did the trick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is indeed the namespace manager.

```
xmlns="http://www.profibus.com/GSDML/2003/11/DeviceProfile"
```

means that everything is in that namespace (unless another default is declared, or an element declares its own namespace).  You will need to use a namespace manager to search in that namespace.

Comment: Okay, edited the question to include the (wrong?) code I tried to handle that with.

Comment: Edited again (finally got it working). Thanks for helping me out, would have tried alot else first if you didn't tell me the namespace actually was the problem.

Comment: You wrote the answer in your second problem in the question, but I'll rewrite it here for anyone looking in the future.  You have to specify the namespace on each part: "/iso:ISO15745Profile/iso:ProfileBody/iso:ApplicationProcess...."